# Вопрос по mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, php

В общем сделал ЧПУ, но теперь на новом УРЛ не отображаются css стили, подскажите что делать?

З.Ы. 
оригинальный УРЛ: phpblog.loc/viewcat.php?cat=1 - стили CSS работают.
ЧПУ: phpblog.loc/category/1/ - не отображаются CSS стили.

Comment: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/39954/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-rewriterule-%D0%B2-htaccess?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#39972">клац</a>

Comment: О, а я не нашел и ответ уже запостил. Хорошо)

Comment: возникла странная проблема, теперь при переходе с нового урл на другой получается вот такое: допустим я зашел сюда phpblog.loc/category/1/, теперь хочу перейти в заметку с id 2, но получается вот такая фигня phpblog.loc/category/1/category/2/

Comment: Илья, уберите, простите, нафиг, все относительные ссылки вообще и приучитесь всегда (естественно, кроме случаем, когда очень нужно обратное, а это редкость) обращаться от корня сайта. Собственно, у вас уже вторая проблема от этого. Намекаю - исправьте ссылки с "category/1" на "/category/1". 

ЗЫ: где нельзя использовать абсолютные ссылки, там почти всегда можно использовать ссылки с вопроса(`<a href="?param1=15&id=5"></a>`)

Answer (score 1):

Было бы хорошо, если бы вы показали здесь ту часть .htaccess (либо httpd.conf), где у вас описаны правила для ЧПУ. Если косяк действительно в вашей настройке mod_rewrite.

Другой возможный вариант (если предположить, что mod_rewrite настроен правильно) — кривизна ссылок на CSS. Допустим, у вас ссылка на стилевой файл оформлена как filename.css, без указания пути, тогда при запросе стилевого файла для страницы /category/1/ браузер полезет за файлом /category/1/filename.css и т. п. В таком случае используйте абсолютные пути в ссылках (например, /filename.css).

Comment: там косяк в путях, по определению...

Comment: Если бы вы клацнули на первый комментарий, вы бы не повторялись =)